# Which HTML element has the largest number of children of a certain type, for instance tags?

Tags: html, language-agnostic, xslt, xpath

In any language, [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformations), PHP, Ruby, Perl, anything: how can I get the XPath or other path or identifier to the element containing the largest number of `<p>` tags?

Comment: Stuart, do you know why this question is put into the community wiki? This is not a good thing and may explain why there are not so many answers.

Comment: I ticked the box.  I wanted to be open. Why is it a bad thing?

Comment: Because the votes fro the question and the answers do not count to the reputation of their authors. 

It would be a good idea to contact team@stackoverflow.com, explain to them the issue and ask them to revert the questions and answers to non-community-wiki state. Thanks.

Comment: So, for examle in this case everytime anybody votes up your question you are *not* going to receive your deserved 10 points -- these are the rules about the "community wiki".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer supposes that the html input is a well-formed XML document (such as an XHtml document).

**In XSLT 1.0:**

Given the following XML

```
<html>
    <div id='A1'>
        <p/>
        <p/>
    </div>
    <div id='A2'>
        <p/>
        <p/>
        <p/>
        <p/>
    </div>
    <div id='A3'>
        <p/>
        <p/>
        <p/>
    </div>
</html>
```

**This transformation produces the element that has the largest number of `p` children**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElByP" match="*" use="boolean(p)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('kElByP', 'true')">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending"
         select="count(p)"/>

         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on the XML document the correct result is produced**:

```
<div id="A2">
        <p />
        <p />
        <p />
        <p />
    </div>
```

**Using XPath 2.0:**

```
//*[count(p) = max(//*/count(p))]
```

Comment: I've been thinking a while about an XPath 1.0 solution, but I'm not convinced that one exists. What do you say?

Comment: I guess if it's not xhtml I could run a tidy over it first

Comment: @Tomalak No, unless XPath is hosted in XSLT, but even in this case it would be tricky and it is meaningless to look in XSLT for an XPath one-liners that will be less efficient than xslt code. The main reason is that the maximum is on a calculated value. 1-liners exist if the maximum is on elem/attr

Comment: @Tomalak Why recently most questions I answer are put in the community wiki? Causes me a lot of time to find out why my rep doesn't reflect the new votes. Very bad :(

Comment: @Dimitre: Wiki mode is mandatorily inherited from the question, and any post will turn into a wiki after the seventh edit. I suppose that's because people shall think before postings and then stick with a post not changing it too often, or rep becomes meaningless for that post.

Comment: @Dimitre: Regarding XPath 1.0, I knew that it wouldn't be efficient. It was more a thought experiment than anything else, but I couldn't calculate the maximum either. I gave my up-vote earlier today already.

Comment: @Tomalak THe number of revisions is only 2. It seems that many users don't know what the "community wiki" is and they are putting their question there as a kind of "award and recognition". This is the second time in a few days I have this happening. SO needs to fix this.

Comment: @Dimitre: I can feel your irritation. :-) I stumbled over this myself a few times in my early days. Novice users tend to think wiki mode would either benefit them in some way or would otherwise be a sensible thing to do. Just have an eye on it before you answer, it's easily spotted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use getElementsByTagName to find your <p>s and loop through the results to find the greatest value of childNodes.length with Javascript (assuming you have the option to do this on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the language. JavaScript for instance can naturally handle viewing the HTML DOM and there are libraries such as ProtoType that would make quick work of it. Similarly, Garann's answer would get you on your way.

In other languages, I would suggest using regular expressions to find tags that have paragraph tags in them. This would likely involve turning the entire html into a single string and processing it.

Assuming that it is properly formatted HTML, you could strip out all the content, leaving only the tags.  Doing that first would make the subsequent steps move faster.  Then it is likely a matter of some loops and some counters.

Comment: No to regex, DOM structures are not regular

Answer (score 0):

A very brute force solution in Perl, using XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $max=0; # max number of p's
my $path;  # path to the element

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => 
                  { # _all_ is called for every single element in the XML
                    _all_ => sub { # $_ is the element
                                   my $nb_p= $_->children( 'p'); 
                                   if( $nb_p > $max)
                                     { $max= $nb_p; 
                                       $path= $_->xpath;
                                     }
                                 }
                  },
              )
         ->parsefile( $ARGV[0]);
print "$path  ($max p)\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to construct this is a recursive design... I saw the simple 2.0 solution. Oh well. An alternate solution, anyway.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="MaxElements">
            <xsl:call-template name="MaxElements">
                <xsl:with-param name="elements" select="//div[p]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="largestSoFar" select="0"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$MaxElements"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="MaxElements">
    <xsl:param name="elements"/>
    <xsl:param name="largestSoFar"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$elements">
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentNumber" select="count($elements[1]/p)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="LargerNumber" select="if ($CurrentNumber > $largestSoFar) then ($CurrentNumber) else $largestSoFar"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="MaxElements">
                <xsl:with-param name="elements" select="$elements[position()>1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="largestSoFar" select="$LargerNumber"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$largestSoFar"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```